# MD5 always the same for different PDF

Tags: java, md5

I need to calculate the MD5 from a PDF file and it seems that every file has the same MD5: 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'.

The md5 calculation works for: word and txt documents. It also has the same behaviour with images. -> the md5 generated for any image is the same as the md5 from the pdf above..

The only thing I'm doing is:

```
String md5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(file.getInputStream());
```

for testing purposes I took the inputStream to generate a file and the correct file (with content) was generated so it's not like the inputStream is empty or something.

Comment: Tested it on two pdf's and got two different sums. Are you sure you used two different files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This md5 corresponds to empty string, look for error in your code.

Comment: It didn't seem possible since I cán create a word document and validate the correct MD5. BUT.. I've changed to order of: Save document and calculate md5 (md5 was the second thing -> so stream would have been empty prob). So now I calculate the md5 before saving and it's all working. But now I actually wonder why it ever worked with word documents. Shouldn't that inputStream be empty too?

Comment: Nothing more than:
String filePath = "C:\\" + getFileName();
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, new File(filePath)); @triclosan

Comment: looks like this discussion is for another question, 'MD5 always the same for different PDF' already answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you searched for `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`, you'd see that it's the MD5 of an empty string. For some reason, your input stream isn't returning any contents.

Answer (score 0):

d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e is the md5 checksum of the empty string.

Use FileInputStream("filename") as source.